# php hide internal url instead with link to php file?

Tags: php

I do not what the item url link to be visible to the user (page source). In php the link is for example used with

```
$item path = 'http://localhost/test/items/'. $item->name ;
```

Is it possible and how so to change the `'http://localhost/test/items/'` so that the address is actually gathered from another php file?.. so that in page source the url would look something like:

```
item_path = 'http://localhost/test?phpfileurl;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sure you could do something like that but then somone could just use http://localhost/test?phpfileurl to access the data, if you want the users browser to show the page, you need to tell it where to look, there is no way arround that.

Comment: could I not block access to the php file just for the server using certain file permissions?

Comment: search about url rewriting

Comment: yes you can block access to that file in htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `Deny from all` in you **.htaccess** text file